# How to reliably submit an HTML form with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is there a way to submit an HTML form using [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) that is guaranteed to work in all situations?

I elaborate. The common approach seems to be:

```
formElement.submit()
```

That is all good and well except for one thing. Fields of a form are available as attributes of `formElement`, so if there is a field with **name** or **id** "text1", it can be accessed as `formElement.text1`.

This means that if an elements is called "submit" (be it its **name** or its **id**), then `formElement.submit()` will not work. This is because `formElement.submit` won't be a method of the form, but the field with that name. Unfortunately, it's fairly common that submit buttons have a "submit" name or id.

Two examples to illustrate my point. First, the following will NOT work, because an element of the form has name "submit":

```
<form name="example" id="example" action="/">
  <button type="button" name="submit" onclick="document.example.submit(); return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The following will work though. The only difference is that I have removed the name "submit" from the form:

```
<form name="example" id="example" action="/">
  <button type="button" onclick="document.example.submit(); return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So, is there any other way to submit an HTML form using JavaScript?

Comment: pretty annoying... I had the same issue with the "length" property of the form (number of controls) being replaced with the value of a control named "length". In the end I changed the name of the control.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876243/why-does-naming-your-html-form-submit-button-submit-break-things

Comment: Am I stupid if I would suggest to give it just another name..? E.g. `"action"` or `"run"`.

Comment: @BalusC: for a single script in a specific site, changing the name will suffice indeed. However, if you want to build a library to use in multiple sites, you need to provide for the most general case. Changing the name is not an option there.

Comment: Great explanation of why form.submit() may not work; solved my problem!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Create another form in JavaScript, and apply its `submit()` method on your original form:

```
<html>
    <script>
        function hack() {
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            var myForm = document.example;
            form.submit.apply(myForm);
        }
    </script>

    <form name="example" id="example" method="get" action="">
        <input type="hidden" value="43" name="hid">
        <button 
          type="button" 
          name="submit" 
          onclick="hack();return false;"
        >Submit</button>
    </form>
</html>
```

`form.submit` is the reference to a fresh and clean submit method, and then you use `apply(myForm)` to execute it with the original form.

Answer (score 2):

> So, is there any other way to submit an HTML form using JavaScript?

**Update**: Take the advice of Jerome (elsewhere in this thread). I'll leave this answer up for historical interest, but it isn't as nice or reliable as Jerome's solution.

The following approach is ugly, but works.

```
    var x = document.forms.example;
    var f = document.createElement('form');
    f.action = x.action;
    f.method = x.method;
    f.enctype = x.enctype;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.elements.length; i++) {
        var el = x.elements[i];
        if (el.name !== "submit") {
            f.appendChild(el);
        }
    }
    x.parentNode.replaceChild(f,x);
    f.submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox

```
formElement.constructor
```

returns "HTMLFormElement". So you can submit the form by using:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(formElement)
```

You can extend this to other browsers as well:

```
formElement.constructor.prototype.submit.call(formElement)
```

Comment: However, not all browsers expose `constructor` on form elements (or any other host object, for that matter).

Comment: Obviously this is not cross browser

Answer (score 1):

The best idea is to not name a submit button 'submit', but you can get around it-

```
function reallysubmitform(n){
 n= n || 0;
 var f= document.forms[n];
 f.onsubmit= function(){
  return true
 };
 var sub= f.elements['submit'];
 if(sub && sub.type== 'submit') sub.click();
 else f.submit();
}
```

**reallysubmitform()**

Comment: It really solved one of my issues, where I cant change the name of the submit button even though I have the form HTML in my file, as I have to submit on external server and they had a check on if the form submitted is having a SUBMIT element or not.

Answer (score 0):

Submiting a form using JavaScript **cannot by design be safe**.

Your users can browse your web site on their phone, have disabled JavaScript, tweaked the source of your page, or using [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29).

In any case, for accessibility purposes, you will need the good  old HTML submit button and some input checks on the server side.

Comment: Of course, but sensible enhancements can still be added that make use of these features. As for "safety", I wasn't asking for it: it was reliability that I wanted, in the form of a stable interface

Answer (score 0):

For a form named submit just calling its buttons click function works for me.

```
document.forms[0].submit.click();  //where submit here is just the name of the button/input tied to the form.
```

Comment: When I originally asked the question, I was developing a JS library. I had to assume as little as possible about the environment. Therefore, this solution would not have worked for me, as I would have had to assume that users would use the correct markup.

Answer (score 0):

Just use onsubmit ...

```
<form name="example" id="example" action="/" onsubmit="document.example.submit();">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="document.example.submit(); return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
```