# jquery form not submitting

Tags: jquery

For some reason everything works with my code but the form will not submit.

```
$(function(){

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen:false,
                    bgiframe: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    //height:auto,
                    width:500,
                    modal: true,
                    overlay: {
                        backgroundColor: '#000',
                        opacity: 0.5
                    },
                    buttons: {
                        'I Agree': function() {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            $('#form1').submit()                    

                        },
                        'I Do Not Agree': function() {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });

            $("#submit").click(function(){

                $("#dialog").dialog('open');


            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed my button outside of the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess (you haven't shown the HTML) that the form contains a form control with the name or id `submit` which clobbers the submit method of the form.

The easiest solution is to rename the control, otherwise see [How to reliably submit an HTML form with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999891/how-to-reliably-submit-an-html-form-with-javascript)

Comment: Actually I used a button, there is no element with the name submit.

Comment: Hint: "I'd guess (you haven't shown the HTML)" implies that it would be a good idea to provide some more of your code. Preferably also a link to the page in question.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a copy/paste of your code? Because you're actually missing a semicolon at the end of the $('#form1').submit().

Comment: Yeah I fixed that, sorry. Same problem though.