# JSON Post request is showing 200 success, but script is not executing

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

FrontEnd
this gets the name, age, city puts it in a JSON format and sends it to localhost:5100/getJson which is my backend.

```
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Age:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age" name="age">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">City:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="Enter city" name="city">
        </div>
        <button onclick = "MyFunction()" id = "submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <p id = "demo">

        </p>
        <script>

            function MyFunction() {
                var name = document.getElementById("name").value
                var age = document.getElementById("age").value
                var city = document.getElementById("city").value
                jsonRequest = {"name":name, "age":age, "city":city}

                fetch('http://localhost:5100/acceptJson', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: jsonRequest
                }).then(res => res.json())

            }
        </script>
```

my backend is a flask server in python.

Backend

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/acceptJson',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def acceptJson():
    jsonData = request.json
    name = jsonData['name']
    age = jsonData['age']
    city = jsonData['city']
    postToDatabase(name,age,city)
    return "Succesful"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = "localhost", port = 5100)
```

Now when I make the same JSON post request using software like Postman it works, returns 200 and runs the script.

[image: Postman working image]

but when I do it through the code, it return 200 and doesn't run the script, so it's clearly something wrong with the POST in the javascript, but I do not understand where it's wrong.

Comment: `body: JSON.stringify(jsonRequest)`

Comment: @Barmar now it's not even sending the request no 200 anymore hmmm

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab of DevTools?

Comment: it just says "finished" in the network tab, console is empty.

Comment: And what do you see if you look at the response?

Comment: @Barmar failed to fetch promise.catch(async) ?

Comment: @Barmar oh it says cannot read propert "request content" of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to your front-end. In the following answer, I assume your form is submitted by "MyFunction".

In this line of HTML:

```
<button onclick = "MyFunction()" id = "submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

The button is a submit type button. When you click the button, the browser submits the form as usual. With no "action" attribute in the  tag, the request is submitted to the webpage you open i.e. no request was sent to the back-end.

The solution can be found in this question: [Form not submitting with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035889/form-not-submitting-with-js). However, I would suggest another method to do so.

You may add "event.preventDefault();" before you call the function of handling the request or add it to the beginning of the function to stop the form from being submitted automatically in a traditional way.

```
<button onclick = "event.preventDefault();MyFunction()" id = "submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

The reason why to use preventDefault is that it only stop the browser default behavior while other solution (return false) stop the event  propagating the DOM.

Comment: HOLY CRAP you actually solved it!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you so much!!!!!!!! this has been bugging me for days!

Comment: You can also change it to `type="button"`